# Diag function om multiple dimensions in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, diagonal

I would like to use the diag() function on a list of vectors, so as to get a list of matrices where the diagonals are the vectors of my list.

To be more specific, suppose I have a list called `list` of 100 vectors with 14 values each.

```
>dim(list)
100 14
```

I would like to create an array `array` of 100 matrices of size 14x14, where the diagonal of the matrix `diag2vec(array[i,,])` is my vector `list[i,]` (all other values in the matrix to be `0`).

So I would end up with:

```
>dim(array)
100 14 14
```

I tried using the diag() function, but I cannot get it to work row-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(M <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6
sapply(1:nrow(M), function(i) diag(M[i, ]), simplify = "array")
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    3    0
# [3,]    0    0    5
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    0    0
# [2,]    0    4    0
# [3,]    0    0    6
```

Also, note that `M` is a matrix, not a list, and that `dim` applied to the last object returns `3 3 2`, which is what you really want I think, instead of `2 3 3` as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Too quick with first attempt.

Using `library(abind)`

```
library(abind)
abind(lapply(x, diag), along = 0)
```

where `x` is assumed to be your list of vectors

Comment: I don't think this stacks quite right. `x[1,4,1]` has a non zero.

Comment: @NealFultz you're right, I was too quick.  Have edited answer to use `library(abind)`

Answer (score 0):

Assumming your data looks like this:

```
z <- replicate(100, runif(14), simplify=FALSE)
```

try:

```
z2 <- aperm(vapply(z, diag, diag(14)), 3:1)
```

which has:

```
> dim(z2)
[1] 100  14  14
```